# Does the telegram public channel get views if i preview it from browser?

Tags: telegram, activesupport, social-media

does the telegram public channel get views if I preview it from browser
wanted to ask that if a public telegram channel get views if I preview that channel from browser by writing (https://t.me/(channel_name))

did the posts will get view or not